# Physical interpretation of invariant interval

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, invariants

I know that the invariant interval $I$ is the same in all reference frames. However, I don't know what is the physical meaning of $I$. Is it just a quantity for us to check our answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It measures the "wristwatch time" $\tau$ between two events. This is the time read on a wristwatch that passes through both events at constant velocity in special relativity and along a geodesic in general relativity. [The straight path with constant velocity is a geodesic too. Special relativity is a special case of general relativity, of course.] This is because $\tau$  is invariant and $dx=dy=dz=0$ in the wristwatch frame so $d\tau=cdt$. Check out [Exploring Black Holes](https://www.eftaylor.com/exploringblackholes/) by Taylor and Wheel. It explains that an object moving in a gravitational field takes the path of maximal aging. This is something that most books on GR oddly don't stress.

Answer (score 1):

For nearby timelike-related events A and B, the invariant interval is equal to the proper-time elapsed (as measured by a wristwatch) along the inertial worldline [a geodesic curve] from event A to B. (In special relativity, one can drop the "nearby" restriction.)

It is analogous to the length of the displacement vector (as measured by a ruler or odometer) from point A to point B in Euclidean space.